# 'Cannot subscript a value of type [[DataMode]]' while trying to divide NSObject arrays in multiple TableView sections

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to divide 2 NSObject arrays in 2 different sections in a TableView, but I see an error in xCode 'Cannot subscript a value of type [[DataMode]].

My DataModel is:

```
class dataModel: NSObject {
    var name:String
    var val:Double
    var prot:Double
    var fat:Double
    var cal:Double
    var grams:Double
    var total:Double

    init(name: String, val: Double,prot: Double, fat: Double, cal:Double, grams: Double, total: Double){
        self.name = name
        self.val = val
        self.prot = prot
        self.fat = fat
        self.cal = cal
        self.grams = grams
        self.total = total
    }  
}
```

Arrays:

```
var MeatData = [dataModel(name: "food1", val: 5.0, prot: 17.5, fat: 11.7, cal:178.0, grams: 0.0, total: 0.0),
    dataModel(name: "meat2", val: 6.0, prot: 19.0, fat: 7.8, cal: 148, grams: 0.0, total: 0.0),
    dataModel(name: "meat3", val: 7.0, prot: 24.5, fat: 29.7, cal: 370.0, grams: 0.0, total: 0.0)]


var BreadData = [dataModel(name: "bread1", val: 5.0, prot: 17.5, fat: 11.7, cal: 178.0, grams: 0.0, total: 0.0),
    dataModel(name: "bread2", val: 6.0, prot: 19.0, fat: 7.8, cal: 148, grams: 0.0, total: 0.0),
    dataModel(name: "bread3", val: 7.0, prot: 24.5, fat: 29.7, cal: 370.0, grams: 0.0, total: 0.0)]
```

TableViewController:

import UIKit

```
class MeatTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let sections = ["Meat","Bread"]
    let items = [[MeatData], [BreadData]]

    @IBOutlet weak var addBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    var stringToPass = ""
    var valueToPass:Double!
    var protToPass:Double!
    var fatToPass:Double!
    var calToPass:Double!

    //vars additional food

    var NewFood = ""
    var NewCarbs:Double!
    var NewProt:Double!
    var NewFat:Double!
    var NewCal:Double!

    var NewlyAddedFood = dataModel(name: "", val: 0.0, prot: 0.0, fat: 0.0, cal: 0.0, grams: 0.0, total: 0.0)

    @IBOutlet var meatTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return self.sections[section]
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return items[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("meatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MeatTableViewCell
        let cellIdentifier = "meatCell"
        let Meatcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MeatTableViewCell
        let meatIndex = MeatData[indexPath.row]

        Meatcell.titleLabel?.text = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        //Meatcell.titleLabel.text = meatIndex.name
        //Meatcell.valLabel.text = String(meatIndex.val)
        //Meatcell.protEMPTY.text = String(meatIndex.prot)
        //Meatcell.fatEMPTY.text = String(meatIndex.fat)
        //Meatcell.calEMPTY.text = String(meatIndex.cal)

        return Meatcell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            MeatData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    let indexPathVal: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        print("\(indexPathVal)")
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathVal) as! MeatTableViewCell;
        print("\(currentCell)")
        print("\(currentCell.titleLabel?.text!)")

        stringToPass = currentCell.titleLabel.text!
        valueToPass = Double(currentCell.valLabel.text!)
        protToPass = Double(currentCell.protEMPTY.text!)
        fatToPass = Double(currentCell.fatEMPTY.text!)
        calToPass = Double(currentCell.calEMPTY.text!)

        print(stringToPass)
        print(valueToPass)
        print(protToPass)
        print(fatToPass)
        print(calToPass)
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showCalc", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        //Here i am checking the Segue and Saving the data to an array on the next view Controller also sending it to the next view COntroller
        if segue.identifier == "showCalc"{
            //Creating an object of the second View controller
            let DestController = segue.destinationViewController as! CalcViewController
            //Sending the data here
            DestController.passedString = stringToPass
            DestController.passedValue = valueToPass
            DestController.passedProt = protToPass
            DestController.passedFat = fatToPass
            DestController.passedCal = calToPass 
        }
    }

    @IBAction func done(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

        let carDetailVC = segue.sourceViewController as! AdditionalFood

        NewFood = String(carDetailVC.AddedFood)
        NewCarbs = carDetailVC.AddedCarbs
        NewProt = carDetailVC.AddedProteins
        NewFat = carDetailVC.AddedFat
        NewCal = carDetailVC.AddedCal

        NewlyAddedFood.name = NewFood
        NewlyAddedFood.val = NewCarbs
        NewlyAddedFood.prot = NewProt
        NewlyAddedFood.fat = NewFat
        NewlyAddedFood.cal = NewCal

        MeatData.insert(NewlyAddedFood, atIndex: 0)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

As a result I noticed an error message

> 'Cannot subscript a value of type [[DataMode]]'here:
>   Meatcell.titleLabel?.text = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

Comment: You've just nested your arrays too deep. Change `let items = [[MeatData], [BreadData]]` to `let items = [MeatData, BreadData]`. And don't forget your vegetables. :)

Comment: Mike, thanks for your answer, but the result is the same.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm trying to Index sections with an NSObject array and I'm not doing it as it should be done. Any help including pointing to some tutorials would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone has an idea how it can be done?